# Make Google Sheets remember data

Tags: google-sheets

Currently, I'm working with large databases in which we store information on assets. It also contains a monthly inspection section in which one can sign off if some inspection has been conducted.

Until now I've made a new file every year in which only the inspection section is the part that differs from the previous file.

What I'd like to do is to have the inspection section (some collection of columns and rows) to show all the signed months from some year (in essence needing sheets to remember the previous years.)

So basically if I'd select 2020, I'd expect an empty array. But if I'd select 2019 in a drop-down menu, I'd like to see all the signed off months within the one and same array.

I already tried copy pasting the results in separate tabs and just copy paste but that would make for a huge file.

What I'd expect (x meaning it's signed off):

```
2020
A     B      C
-     -      -
2019
A     B      C
x     x      x
```

I'd like to switch between those years within the same sheet and within the same set of cells.

Comment: does https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/43085/reference-data-from-another-spreadsheet-in-google-docs-drive help?

Comment: Welcome. The question is too broad and it's not clear. Is this question about using formulas, Google Apps Script or the Google Sheets API?

Comment: Going out on a limb, but could you stack all of your years of data in one tab (assuming the columns are the same for each year), and prepend the year into column A? Then you can have another tab with a drop down for year, and a QUERY formula referencing your first tab, selecting all the columns you'd like and filtering to where year = {{drop down cell}}. It may sound complicated if you're not super familiar with Google Sheets, but we can help with it.